# C# & ASP.NET MVC - getting 404 for controller/method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was provided a zip file for an ASP.NET MVC application (suppose to be source code for our production website done by a contractor) and I am trying to get it to work on my laptop.

I am filling out contact information on a form and clicking the Submit button and I get a weird pop window. I have been reviewing the controller, model and view code and I am stuck, not sure why its not working. The production code works fine.

[Screenshot of Popup Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfjCb.png)

[Screenshot of IE Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unxKR.png)

I am seeing a 404 message and it looks like it can't find a method in my controller. In IE using the Developer Tools in the Console section I am seeing a post to http://localhost/Account/VerifyPhone 404 (not found). I looked at the controller and see the `Verifyphone` method and set a breakpoint, but that breakpoint is not getting hit.

It looks like a Javascript file called `validate-email.js` calls `validateBusinessForm()`, which then calls `validateCellPhone`. I do see in the json that it has the phone number and address information entered on form.

Javascript code `validateCellPhone`:

```
function validateCellPhone(cell, address) {
    var regex = /[^\d]/;
    var decision = false;
    if (regex.test(cell)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid phone number format. (format: XXXXXXXXXX)");
        $("#txtCell").focus();
        decision = false;
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/VerifyPhone', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: { phone: cell, address: address },
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.phoneExists && ngon.ExistingUser == false) {
                    alert("The provided phone number already exists in the system. Please login as a returning customer. You will now be forwarded to the login page.");
                    window.location.replace("/Home");
                    disableErrorMsg = true;
                    decision = false;
                }
                else {
                    decision = true;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                var readyState = {
                    1: "Loading",
                    2: "Loaded",
                    3: "Interactive",
                    4: "Complete"
                };
                if (xhr.readyState !== 0 && xhr.status !== 0 && xhr.responseText !== undefined) {
                    alert("readyState: " + readyState[xhr.readyState] + "\n status: " + xhr.status + "\n\n responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }

            }
        });
```

Controller code - `AccountController.VerifyPhone`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VerifyPhone(string phone)
{
    AddressPhone ap = null;

    try
    {
        ap = HelperFunctions.VerifyPhoneExists(phone);
        ap.Phone = phone;
        Session["AddressPhone"] = ap;

        return Json(ap, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        return Redirect("~/Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: check your route to Controller and try to modify `[HttpPost]` -> `[HttpPost("VerifyPhone")]`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your VerifyPhone method is getting a string parameter (phone) but in JavaScript you are calling to VerifyPhone with parameters which are don't match that's why it tries to find VerifyPhone method and cannot find, so returns 404 not found.

Comment: I updated the C# method in the AccountController by adding a parameter string address to the method signature.  I then re-ran the application and still getting the 404 error message.   I am stumped on this.

Comment: I believe I have figured this out, in the javascript file I change the url from url: '/Account/VerifyPhone to /R2S/Account/VerifyPhone